# Creating a Keras function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When creating a Keras function with the new tf2 I get a strange error that appears to be a bug, as I have used this same code before with a different model architecture, and that should not effect this.

Details on the model shapes are a (N,M,X) input and (N,M) output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question by further specifying the input and output positions.

`K.function(model.layers[0].get_input_at(0), model.layers[-1].get_output_at(0))`